# Dynamic carousel slider 3 slides per page

Tags: php, mysql, owl-carousel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfZko.png)

I need to display 3 date items each time in Bootstrap carousel in PHP using while loop, I want to display 3 date items in one slide and next slide have another 3 data items and so on.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php  
   date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $end_date = '2018-11-05';   ?>

     <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner" >

            <?php $i_count = 1;  ?>       

              <?php  if($i_count==1){ ?>   
              <div class="item active"> 
              <?php   }
               else if($i_count%3==0) {  ?>  
               <div class="item"> 
                <?php } ?>          

               <div class="col-md-12 pa-0">
                  <?php  
                 while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date))   
                   {
                    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));  
                   ?>  

                  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pa-0 <?php if ($i_count == 1 || $i_count == 2 || $i_count == 3 ) echo ' activeday'?>">

                        <div class="date-heading">
                            <div class="day-of-week"><?=  date('l', strtotime($date)); ?></div>
                            <div class="date-secondary pb-5"><?=  date('F d', strtotime($date)); ?></div>
                            <div class="date-head-text"><?=  date('l', strtotime($date)); ?></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="choose-time">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <input class="time-selection" name="time[]" data-readable-date="2018-02-03" value="2018-02-03 06:15" id="appt1517638500" data-original-text="2018-02-03 06:15" type="radio">
                                <label id="lbl_appt1517638500" for="appt1517638500" data-original-text="11:45">11:45</label><br>                        

                            </div> 
                        </div>     

                  </div>
                  <?php } ?>                    
                </div>

            </div>
           <?php $i_count++; ?>

        </div>
        <a href="#carousel-example-captions" role="button" data-slide="prev" class="left carousel-control"> 
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-caret-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a> 
        <a href="#carousel-example-captions" role="button" data-slide="next" class="right carousel-control" >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a> 
    </div>
```

Comment: What problem are you having with this? "Not working" is not a very actionable fault report.

Comment: i need to display next 3 date items in another slide.. but in my code showing in same screen..